# Hide/Unhide toggle of nav links across different Routes in React Router V4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have some Routes in my application in which I have common a header and
a nav links.

Currently, I got a requirement where in few routes, I want to show just the `header` only and not `nav` links.

Take the following example, Suppose for `/billing` route, I don't want to show the nav links for it.

How could I do toggling of hide/unhide link across different routes?

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <header>
        <Logo />
        <Search />
        <ActionButtons />
      </header>

      <BrowserRouter>
        <nav>
          <Link exact to="/">
            Home
          </Link>
          <Link exact to="/about">
            About
          </Link>
          <Link exact to="/contact">
            Contact us
          </Link>
        </nav>

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/contact">
            <Contact />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/cafeteria">
            <Cafeteria />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/billing">
            <Billing />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could render the navbar into a route and specify all the routes you want it to match and render on.

Example:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <header>
        <Logo />
        <Search />
        <ActionButtons />
      </header>

      <BrowserRouter>
        <nav>
          <Route
            exact
            path={["/about", "/contact", "/cafeteria", "/"]}
          >
            <Link exact to="/">
              Home
            </Link>
            <Link exact to="/about">
              About
            </Link>
            <Link exact to="/contact">
              Contact us
            </Link>
          </Route>
        </nav>

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/contact">
            <Contact />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/cafeteria">
            <Cafeteria />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/billing">
            <Billing />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}
```

If you've a large number of routes then it may be more practical to use routes you want to exclude the rendering.

Example:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <header>
        <Logo />
        <Search />
        <ActionButtons />
      </header>

      <BrowserRouter>
        <nav>
          <Route
            render={({ location }) => {
              return ["/billing"].some(path => location.pathname === path)
                ? null
                : (
                  <>
                    <Link exact to="/">
                      Home
                    </Link>
                    <Link exact to="/about">
                      About
                    </Link>
                    <Link exact to="/contact">
                      Contact us
                    </Link>
                  </>
                );
            }}
          />
        </nav>

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/contact">
            <Contact />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/cafeteria">
            <Cafeteria />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/billing">
            <Billing />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I thought `Route` can only reside as children of `Switch`. I think I am missing the documentation of where `Route` can be used outside `Switch`.

Comment: @SubratoPattanaik Is there any documentation that says you can only use a `Route` inside a `Switch`? When `Route` components are rendered only within a `Router` they are inclusively matched, whereas if rendered within a `Switch` they are exclusively matched. The difference is outside a `Switch` any and all matched routes are rendered, inside only the first match is rendered.

Comment: @SubratoPattanaik No worries. If/when you do upgrade to `react-router-dom@6` be aware that the `Switch` component was *effectively*** replaced by a `Routes` component that handles route matching, and ***it is required*** to render all `Route` components into a `Routes` component. Cheers and good luck.